# DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL Tweaking Configuration in Jayway JsonPath doesnot return null for inner arrays

Tags: jsonpath

I have a json string like:

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "authorextra": [
              {
                "auth1":"Nigel Rees",
                "auth2":"xxxx"
              }
              ],
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

I have used the DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL option while parsing the json.

```
ReadContext ctx=JsonPath.using(Configuration.builder().options(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).build()).parse(input);
```

When i read this path :

```
returnObj = ctx.read($.store.book[*].authorextra[*].auth1);
```

I get the result as :
    [
   "Nigel Rees"
]

I am expecting :
[
"Nigel Rees",
null,
null,
null
]

What configuration am i missing here? Any help is appreciated. TIA !

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have overlooked the LEAF part of the DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL setting. Your path has store --> book --> authorextra --> auth1. So the leafs that will be set to NULL are those auth1 missing for authorextra. As the first book is the only one having authorextra, it is the only one giving you result, as it is the only one where you can look for a leaf. If you try this other json document:

```
{
   "store" : {
      "book" : [
         {
            "category" : "reference",
            "authorextra": [
              {
                "auth1":"Nigel Rees",
                "auth2":"xxxx"
              }
              ],
            "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
            "price" : 8.95
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "authorextra": [
              {
                "auth2":"Evelyn Waugh"
              }
              ],
            "title" : "Sword of Honour",
            "price" : 12.99
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "author" : "Herman Melville",
            "title" : "Moby Dick",
            "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
            "price" : 8.99
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
            "price" : 22.99
         }
      ],
      "bicycle" : {
         "color" : "red",
         "price" : 19.95
      }
   },
   "expensive" : 10
}
```

You would get ["Nigel Rees", null], because the second book also has authorextra, but has missing auth1, that is, the leaf.

Comment: Thanks Jorge for highlighting the significance of "LEAF". Now i get the behaviour. But my use case requires  [ "Nigel Rees", null, null, null ] to be returned. What configuration would hold good for my scenario. ( If there was a DEFAULT_PATH_TO_NULL..)

Comment: @Shruthi Could you put an empty `authorextra` in the `book` element? That way you would get the correct output, although you would also get longer documents. I usually work with XPaths instead of JsonPath, so I'm not expert on this, but it looks like JsonPath would not let you return elements from different levels as you need with your document structure (you are mixing in the output book-->null elements with authextra-->auth1 elements)